# No hats on the mobile version?

Tags: support, mobile-web, winter-bash

I was wondering why there is not hats available on the mobile version. No hats on avatar, no hats counts, etc ..

[image]

Is it because it seems to be an ajax layer over all websites? or the same reason there is no helpful tag counts?

Comment: My guess would be that the amount of effort it would cannot be justified considering it's a short-term feature.

Comment: In addition, most mobile users wouldn't want their data cap to be used up by the extra bandwidth needed for this.

Comment: @oded hats are more important than data limits

Comment: This is global to all Winter Bash, in all years, retagged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mobile site is designed to be lightweight, a lot of features are missing<sup>1</sup>. The hats are heavy-ish on page load, since they are mainly implemented in JS<sup>2</sup>.

Users on mobile have good page load times as the goal, not hats.

Also, it would be a pain to code an opt-in mobile version of hats if not that many people would use it.

<sup>1. I hate this as well, I used to be an avid user of the mobile site (not so much anymore, due to completely unrelated reasons). But I used to agree with this, and I still do</sup>

<sup>2. If this was a permanent feature, I guess they would have hard-baked it into the C# serverside code, but this isn't</sup>

Answer (score 6):

If you really want the hats (and are using iOS) just flick up until you can see the bottom of the page and select the **full site** link that is to the right of "contact us" and you will be able to view all the hat folly you care to see from a mobile Safari.