# Badges in user card got incorrect position in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, badges, mobile-web, user-card

Circles for user's badges drawed in wrong positions for mobile web:

> [image: badges]

Tested in Chrome 55 on Android.

Comment: Also, no hats are displayed.

Comment: Please stick with one bug report/feature request per question. The hats for mobile are already reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159559/no-hats-on-the-mobile-version)

Comment: [It used to be bit different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250819/in-the-mobile-version-badges-are-aligned-badly-in-the-user-cards), they probably tried to fix that and came with this new design.

Comment: They're [a lot smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrRsG.png) on every (desktop and mobile) browser I have which makes the positioning less of a problem.