# Whatever in a list is too close to the following list item in mobile web

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

See the picture. Don't you think whatever before the next list item is too close?

[image]

If you have a mobile, you can see it below (added various cases). You can always check the source of this post by clicking the [edit](/posts/304082/edit) button below.

---

1. A list item

   > Blockquote
2. Another list item

   ```
   Code block
   ```
3. An extra list item

   Regular paragraph
4. Last list item

---

I believe the browser doesn't matter, but in case it does, I can tell you it's **Google Chrome 62.0.3202.84** from Google Play, running on **OnePlus 5**, **Android 7.1.1**.

Comment: Dear. This looks satisfactorily fine on desktop web.

Comment: [Another design bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288309/339911) is visible on your picture.

Comment: Looks like this is not exclusive to blockquotes.